# JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided. While verifying token

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

`const token = req.cookies.admintoken;`
`const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.ADMIN_SECRET_KEY);`

above is my code, while executing second line it gives error
`JsonWebTokenError: jwt must be provided`
this code is perfectly working for user side but giving error in Admin side.

Comment: `console.log(token)` to check if it exists

Comment: Token is already exists, problem is in jwt.verify line